# Duplicate urls when redirect .php to non-php urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a redirect system in my .htaccess, but sometimes when I crawl my site with some program like scremingfrog to verify my site has no problems, I get duplicate urls with `php` in the path name as illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: Output when crawling own site]

This is my .htaccess code:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
    
<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

How can i solve that?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the first argument of `RewriteRule` in a .htaccess file guaranteed never starts with a slash. Other than that, the only thing that might happen is that `^[A-Z]{3,9}` does not match a lowercase "get", which I think is not prohibited. Might want to try with `[^\ ]+\ /([^\ ]+)\.php` instead.

Comment: if i try this i will get redirect any way?